# Why will my shutter not work with a bayonet mount lens and pop-up flash being used?

Tags: troubleshooting, nikon-d90, shutter

This was working fine yesterday. I have an older bayonet mount lens on Nikon D90 and am using a pop-up flash in commander mode. I turned on the camera today and no shutter when pop-up is ON. I turned off the pop-up flash and shutter works. I changed to newer lens and there are no problems. This is a new issue.

All shooting is done in manual mode. I cleaned the contacts, charged the battery, and have put an old lens on and off the camera. What is the problem? Did my settings get changed somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The pop-up flash relies on TTL metering to determine how powerful it will have to be to produce a correct exposure. Old nikon lenses (that is, non D/G lenses) do not relay focusing distance data to the camera, and thus won't work with TTL metering. If you use your flash in manual mode (not entirely sure how to do this... maybe someone else can elaborate?) you should be able to use your lens just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you see any symbol resembling -33 on display then you may have a problem with the lens and mount. But since you said you camera works fine when flash is off then second answer might be your problem.

But if you  don't then I guess you're using a shutter speed faster than 1/250 second. Pop-up flashes support shutters equal to or slower than 1/250.